# Structuring States Node in Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

In order to store all the states and districts with unique key value, I have written the following, but data is always overwritten.

```
Map<String, Object> dist = new HashMap<>();
dist.put(item.getDistrict().toLowerCase(), item.getDistrict());

 ref.child("States")
    .child(state.toLowerCase())
    .child("Districts")
    .setValue(dist, callback);



 States 
  - andhrapradesh
    -name: "Andhra Pradesh" 
    -Districts
       - vizag
           - name : Vizag
       - eastgodavari
           - name: East Godavari
```

How to push the data correctly for the first time. Next time I have to get all states at once, based on the states selection, I have to show the districts in UI.

Can anyone help me on this approach ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To update the existing districts, use `updateChildren()`:

```
ref.child("States")
   .child(state.toLowerCase())
   .child("Districts")
   .updateChildren(dist, callback);
```

I highly recommend reading the Firebase [guide](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/save-data#update_specific_fields) and [reference](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/DatabaseReference.html#updateChildren) documentation.

Answer (score 1):

You can give the node a unique key generated by firebase using the push method on any firebase database reference, but if you want to use your own key be sure that you use updateChildren method instead of setValue method